# Нужна помощь с Retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, retrofit

Мы с другом только начинаем изучать android, посмотрите что не так? может как-то не так строим приложение или вызываем что-то не то? https://github.com/GlebShahov/Test-master.

Хотелось бы понять как сделать так, чтобы данные с сервера сэтились в Imageview. И в каком месте вызывать метод, работающий с инетом. Я сделал классы апи (там у меня гет запрос), app, затем для отображения списка картинок использовал recycler, создал фрагмент, через фрагмент менеджер соединил активити и фрагмент, если в общих чертах, но что-то где-то упустил.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: @ШаховГлеб ViewHolder выкиньте в отдельный файл

Comment: @ШаховГлеб вот у вас есть метод bind.  Вот в нем вы должны засунуть в ImageView изоюражение. Для этого используйте одну из библиотек: Fresco, Glide, Picasso, которые принимают ссылку на изображение

Comment: А так вроде все нормально. Только вы слишком высоко инициализируете Api, аж в App

Comment: Как я понял вы используйте паттерн MVP. Посмотрите тогда в сторону Moxy, она решит одну из проблем, связанных с изменением конфигурации

Comment: @danilshik да я кстати тоже думал что проблема где то в bind. Спасибо за подсказку про библиотеки, вообще не слышал, если честно про них. Да именно MVP, прохожу курсы, мы на них изучали. Пытаюсь с ещё одним учеником сделать примерно тоже самое и какое то фиаско. Спасибо, что уделили время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я посмотрел ваш код из основных ошибок:
1. У вас toolbar находится не в корневом лейауте.
2. Неправильно указана библиотека! Должно быть примерно так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".screen.MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#908070"
        android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFAFA" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info_24dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/small_oval_nonactive"
                android:text="Топ-10" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/small_oval_nonactive"
                android:text="Магазины" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/small_oval_nonactive"
                android:text="Товары" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

3. Немного переписал ApiInitilazer

   public class ApiInitilaizer {

   ```
   private static final String BASE_URL = "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sl.files/";
   private static ApiInitilaizer sApiInitilaizer;
   private static Api sApi;


   private ApiInitilaizer(){
       Gson gson = createGson();
       OkHttpClient okHttpClient = createClient();
       Retrofit sRetrofit = createRetrofit(gson, okHttpClient);

       sApi = sRetrofit.create(Api.class);
   }

   public static synchronized ApiInitilaizer getInstance() {
       if (sApiInitilaizer == null) {
           sApiInitilaizer = new ApiInitilaizer();
       }
       return sApiInitilaizer;
   }

   public static Api getApi() {
       return sApi;
   }

   private Gson createGson() {
       return new GsonBuilder()
               .create();
   }

   private OkHttpClient createClient() {
       HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
       interceptor.setLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);


       return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
               .addInterceptor(interceptor)
               .build();
   }

   private Retrofit createRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient client) {
       return new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
               .client(client)
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
   ```

   //             .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                   .build();
       }
   }

Что-то возможно было еще! Если что вот здесь можете посмотреть всю проделанную работу! https://github.com/industradamus/Test-master

И раз уж вы используете MVP я бы посоветовал посмотреть эту ссылочку https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/473-mvp-na-primere-jekrana-s-pin-kodom.html